# JavaScript Refreshes Instead of Changing Pages

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to figure out why my page will not redirect to the set page. Whenever the condition is met, the page simply refreshes. I have gone into the browser console and pasted my redirect code, and it does redirect.

Full JavaScript Function:

```
    function formSubmit(){
        var formFN = document.getElementById("fName");
        var formLN = document.getElementById("lName");

        if( formFN.value.length == 0 || formFN.value == null){
            window.alert("Please enter your first name.");
            return false;
        }
        else if( formLN.value.length == 0 || formLN.value == null){
            window.alert("Please enter your last name.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.location = "resultPage.html";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

HTML Part:

```
<div id="form">
        <form action="">
        <h3>Thanks for visiting!</h3>
            <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fName" value="">
            <br>
            <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lName" value="">
            <br>
            <button onclick="formSubmit();">
                Submit
            </button>
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit();"> -->
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` to each block and run the page again.

Comment: How your validation function is being called ?

Comment: @Rayon I am calling this by clicking on a button

Comment: @DavidR Just add it to the end of each? Nothing happened.

Comment: No.. It has to be added after each of your `window.alert...` and `window.location.start...` statements.

Comment: @DavidR Still continues to refresh instead of redirecting.

Comment: This is incomplete and _bad_ question.. You have not shared how function is being executed.. [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) elements have a `type` attribute of `submit`. Based on your question, you probably want this instead:

```
<button type="button" onclick="formSubmit();">
     Submit
</button>
```

If you want a more general solution, you'd be better off capturing and handling the `submit` event on the form since things like pressing return in an `input` would trigger a submit as well.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("form").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].addEventListener("submit",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop the normal action for this event

        var formFN = document.getElementById("fName");
        var formLN = document.getElementById("lName");

        if( formFN.value == null || formFN.value.length == 0 ){
            alert("Please enter your first name.");
        }
        else if( formLN.value == null || formLN.value.length == 0 ){
            alert("Please enter your last name.");
        }
        else {
            document.location = "resultPage.html";
        }
    });
});
```

```
<div id="form">
    <form>
    <h3>Thanks for visiting!</h3>
        <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" value="">
        <br>
        <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName" value="">
        <br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Edit:** It occurs to me that you should check for nulls before checking for length. (If `.value` is `null` then checking `.value.length` will throw an error.) Adjusted code accordingly.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, I did not know that about buttons. Just to make sure I understand, the second solution does exactly the same thing (preventing the button from doing the default submit), but in a "smoother" way?

Comment: @Sakvad Not just the button but all the ways a form could be submitted but the user. (For example, pressing enter in a text field triggers a submit event as well.)